# SearchServiceApplication error

Tags: 2010, search

I'm trying to debug an error in my SharePoint 2010 environment.  I have 2 host named site collections (http://site1.com and http://site2.com) and the user account set in Central admin for the SearchService has access the same access levels for both sites.

However, the search crawler is only finding content under http://site2.com and I'm receiving the following error for http:/site1.com:

The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site: Value does not fall within the expected range. )

The only difference I can think of between these to site collections, is that http://site1.com was once renamed using the Set-SPSite command in PowerShell, but this change was done months ago and site search was working fine up until at least a few weeks ago

Comment: can you provide detailed error you receive or look at ULS log to find what exactly the error is

Comment: I can't find any error in the ULS log (I must admit that I'm not to familiar with the tool though), however the exact error listed in the crawl log (visible through central admin) is:

The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site: Value does not fall within the expected range. )